# How to handle ties in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, groupwise-maximum

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    department_id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    hire_date,
    job_id
FROM employees e
WHERE hire_date IN 
     (
         SELECT max(hire_date)
         FROM employees
         WHERE e.department_id = department_id 
     )
ORDER BY hire_date ASC
```

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdKDB.png)

So this is my query and the result of it. There are two tied results for **SA_REP** department and I should have only one result - for instance the one with the lower employee_id. I've googled the problem but can't seem to find any related results...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could add a similar subquery to the WHERE, checking for it being min of the employee id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `not exists` query which gives you more flexibility:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                                                  -- no x exists that...
    SELECT *
    FROM employees x
    WHERE x.department_id = e.department_id                         -- belongs to same department 
    AND (
        x.hire_date > e.hire_date OR                                -- but hired later than e
        x.hire_date = e.hire_date AND x.employee_id < e.employee_id -- hired on same date but has lesser employee id than e
    )
)
```

Comment: worked like charm, except one ">" --- must be x.hire_date = e.hire_date AND x.employee_id < e.employee_id in order to show the lower ID of the two

Comment: I thought you wanted to keep the one with the lower employee_id?

Comment: Yes, the lower one is with "<" not ">". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `RANK` analytic function here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id
                             ORDER BY hire_date DESC, employee_id) rnk
    FROM employees e
)

SELECT employee_id, department_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date, job_id
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Rank respects ties. he wants the opposite.

Comment: @SalmanA Any reason why we cannot add more sorting levels to get the behavior the OP wants here?

Comment: of course, but row_number would be more appropriate (it shows the intent more clearly).